# Table is not creating on SQL server while uploading data using python

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm new to connecting sql server using python.I need to read some data from sql server do the processing & upload the processed data on sql server.All of these task will be done using python. So I have written the code to pull the data from sql server,did the processing & finally while I'm trying to upload the data on sql server then my code is working fine I'm not getting any error message from python.But I'm unable to see the table on SQL Server, even if I'm trying to retrieve the data from sql server using my python code, I'm getting error message

```
 pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'output1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Below is the code I used to insert data onto sql server

```
  conn = sqlite3.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=My server name;'
                                'Database=my data base name;'
                                'uid=my uid;pwd=my password')
c=conn.cursor()
date = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
dataToUpload['OPT_TYPE']=opt_type
dataToUpload['Date']=date
list_opt_output=dataToUpload.values.tolist()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists output1
         (Class text,Location text,Name text,Maths decimal(5,2), nonMaths decimal(5,2), promopercent decimal(5,3),OPT_TYPE text,Date date)''')
conn.commit()
print("Output table created")
c.executemany('''INSERT INTO output1(Class,Location,Name,Maths, nonMaths,promopercent,OPT_TYPE,Date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', list_opt_output)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Can you guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you *sure* you aren't getting any error? You're using `sqlite3` and the syntax `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is invalid. There's `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE OR ALTER` only for programmability objexts like stored procedures, views, triggers and functions

Comment: Use [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017) to connect to SQL Server. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) cover both pyodbc and pymssql but note that : "Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in **pyodbc** driver." Bolds by Microsoft

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no I was not getting any error for `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST`. After this statement I put a print statement "Table Created" & I was getting this message. Also I didn't have any try catch block. Any way after reading your comment I removed the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` & using only `Create table`. I'm running my code. I will let you know once it done

Answer (score 3):

`CREATE TABLE if not exists output1` is not valid `SQL Server` syntax. You can use `IF OBJECT_ID('output1','U') IS NULL` to check if table is present.

Change your query like following.

```
c.execute('''IF OBJECT_ID(''output1'',''U'') IS NULL CREATE TABLE output1
         (Class text,Location text,Name text,Maths decimal(5,2), nonMaths decimal(5,2), promopercent decimal(5,3),OPT_TYPE text,Date date)''')
conn.commit()
```

Comment: But this statement is throwing error message `File "<ipython-input-9-c9177580ee59>", line 2, in <module>
    (Class text,Location text,Name text,Maths decimal(5,2), nonMaths decimal(5,2), promopercent decimal(5,3),OPT_TYPE text,Date date)''')

OperationalError: near "IF": syntax error`

Comment: @Sonia which driver did you use? Did you use `pyodbc` or `pymssql` ?

Comment: You need to check your generated query, it can have additional quotes. Can you try keeping only one quote in the beginning and end

Comment: Hi all, I modified my create statement command use this as create statement command  `c.execute('''CREATE TABLE output1
             (Channel text,Market text,Productlow text,promoprice decimal(5,2), nonpromoprice decimal(5,2), promopercent decimal(5,3),OPT_TYPE text,Date date)''')` But still I got the same error,table is not created.Can yo please help me? @PSK, I'm using `pyodbc`